# Repacing Windows 10 with Ubuntu on a brand new netbook

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

I have just bought a Lenovo ideapad 100S with Windows 10 pre-installed.
I would like, if possible to remove windows using an official Ubuntu DVD before Windows 10 even starts up. I have managed by hitting F12 to enter 'Boot Manager' and switched 'Secure Boot' to OFF. I then went to EFI from USB devices and chose CD/DVD Rom. The message that came up was: "System doesn't have any CD/DVD boot options. Please select other boot options in Boot Manager Menu". So I tried again with USB device instead, message read: "System doesn't have any USB boot options. Please select ...." I knew Windows 10 would be a hard nut to crack as I had experience with Windows 8.1 last year. My question is, is there some way I can install before opening Windows 10 for the first time, or do I have to go through the whole process and attempt an Ubuntu installation from the Windows 10 UI?

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 to stop the booting process, insert the UbuntuLiveCD into your drive. Shut off the computer then start it again and Press F12 .. choose the cd rom drive and it should boot to the Ubuntu LiveCD

If this doesn't work you may have a bad install disc. You may have to download it again and burn it to a new DVD ... If you have any other bootable CD/DVD you can put it in the way I described and see if it will boot to that ... if it does then you can determine that the disc you are trying to use isn't working properly.

Comment: The disc I am using is an official Ubuntu DVD mailed to me in Australia from Ubuntu UK. It was used last year to replace a Windows 8.1 laptop, with eventual success. MS didn't make it easy. This time Windows 10  appears to be a brick wall! See messages in original post.

Comment: maybe I misinterpreted what you said let me see if I understand correctly F12 brings up a menu with all the drives and a selection to boot into the UEFI .. when the cd is in the computer you select the cdrom and it says "System doesn't have any CD/DVD boot options" Can you tell me what version the official Ubuntu DVD is and do you know if it is 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: The reason I keep questioning the disc is because Windows has nothing to do with it right now... this is all UEFI and you said you shut off the things you need to shut off.

Comment: have you tried going to the UEFI and forcing the boot order so that the DVD is  the first  boot item ... then put in the DVD and see if it boots to that or starts to boot to windows and you can shut it down if it tries to start Windows

Comment: As soon as I switched the machine on, I pressed F12. This brought up 'Boot Option Menu" Two options were "EFI Boot Devices" and "Windows Boot Manager". Only "Windows Boot Manager" is available to choose. The other is greyed out. Looks like Windows might have this one neatly sewn up! The title on the Ubuntu DVD is "14.04 LTS Desktop Edition". Finally, I am using an external CD/DVD Rom as the netbook doesn't have a DVD drive.

Comment: Ubuntu DVD is 64bit.

Comment: Ok .. I think 14.04 is EUFI compatible so that probably isn't the issue.. again it can't be Windows .. Windows doesn't control the computers motherboard. This is an issue somehow with the PC maybe not recognizing the external DVD drive properly or something. I would try going into the UEFI/bios directly .. there is somewhere in there that controls the boot order. I would change it so that the DVD boots first .. it should show up in the UEFI/bios.. if it doesn't that could be the problem you may have to use another PC to create a bootable USB.

Comment: The issues you are having would be happening if you had a completely formatted drive in  your PC ... The OS isn't playing a part in this yet

Comment: If you wanted to create a bootable USB and you have a Windows system that you can use Rufus is a good program for that and you could use that Ubuntu DVD to create the Bootable USB.

Comment: The problem is, on this little Lenovo, you can't get near the UEFI/bios. It has very limited options for boot management. Only those I've mentioned.

Comment: there is not an option to enter bios in that menu ... have you tried F2 during boot  .. F12 is the boot menu where F2 i believe on Lenovo's is to enter bios/uefi. I tried to look it up to see if I could get some images of the setup but I can only find the manual and that doesn't cover anything about the bios/uefi

Comment: Sadly, F2 takes me to the same "Information / Configuration / Exit" window I reached via F12. Apart from "Administrator Password" and "Power on Password", "Configuration" only allows for "Secure Boot - On or Off", resets of "Setup Mode" or "Factory Keys", "Hotkey Mode - On or Off" and "BIOS Back Flash - On or Off". That's it. Never mind, I've succumbed to Windows 10 (as much as I hate to). I'm only using the device for PDF and video tutorials, plus some music. I've cut off internet access, etc. The less contact I have with MS, the better! Thanks for trying.

Comment: I think you only choice would have been to create a bootable USB .. i think the removable DVD wasn't capable of booting to it .. it may be a compatibility issue or it just may not have the ability... the bootable USB would probably have worked. Once it was created and plugged in .. you probably would have had the USB option ungray out